# Is it possible to make an Ajax request to a method in a Class Library?

Tags: .net, ajax

Basically, if I have a method (or several methods) that I want to expose to multiple applications, what is the best way to get these to be callable via a jQuery Ajax request?  I'd rather avoid having to copy and paste these methods into an ASHX or something somewhere in every project that requires the functionality.

For example, I have a method that looks up a city and state based on the postal code.  I'd like to call this method from a shared DLL and not have to copy the method or add a method that simply wraps the call to that DLL to every project that requires the lookup functionality.

Should I have some kind of generic "utilities" web service?  That seems like a hackish approach too since it's not really a web service providing an API but just a group of commonly-used methods.

This is with ASP.NET WebForms, not MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with the web service you would have to duplicate the code to call said service from each application.  I would think the same would be true with the MVC application approach but not sure about that.

For me I would just used a shared dll (or service depending on requirements).  Yes you would have to duplicate the code to call that dll from each app but I think it greatly simplifies what you're trying to do.  That's how I tend to view common libraries anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a library called [AjaxPro](http://ajaxpro.info/) .. but it's kinda deprecated =/

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending to use strictly jQuery Ajax method, just wrap what class with MVC application, e.g. so each controller action would invoke each method operating with JSON result.

Comment: Is that the only way?  It's an interesting thought but creating a whole MVC application for shared utilities seems like a worse hack than creating a web service!

Comment: No, of course it's not. But It was most efficient way for me, cuz I had to add this functional to MVC app, that already existed.

Comment: Ah okay.  I'm forced to work with WebForms, so I don't even have the luxury of MVC ;-)

Comment: Consider creating some workaround with empty pages or even creating an own handler, which also would return JSON.

Comment: That was my initial thought - just make an ASHX and wrap the external call; I was hoping there was a way to avoid having to create what amounts to a dummy file in each project that needs to do this.